# Avoid Inheriting Super Class Tests in ScalaTest

Tags: inheritance, scalatest

I'd like to use test code from another project which has tightly coupled some utility methods along with their tests. I would like to inherit from this class so I'm able to use the utility methods but don't want the accompanying tests. Is there a way to inherit from this other Suite without also registering the tests?

I've tried extending from a replica of the class labeled with the @DoNotDiscover annotation but this doesn't seem to have the desired effect.

I'd also be interested if there was some way of just ignoring all the tests inherited form the parent suite as well.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to make an instance of the other suite and hold within my test class. Then call the methods from within the other project's instantiated class using my test code.

This required a bit of overriding since I needed to change a few default parameters made in the other class to fit our testing schema but was relatively painless.

Comment: Were you able to find an alternative? I'm having this exact problem.