# Override or hide tests inherited from a parent suite

Tags: scala, scalatest

Say I have several tests in an abstract class which are intended to be run on several implementations of a trait:

```
trait Foo {
  def method1
  def method2
  // etc.
}

class Foo1 extends Foo { ... }

class Foo2 extends Foo { ... }

class Foo3 extends Foo { ... }

abstract class FooTest extends FunSuite with Matchers {
  val foo: Foo

  test("method1") { foo.method1 should equal(...) }

  test("method2") { ... }
}

class Foo1Tests extends FooTests { val foo = new Foo1 }
...
```

Unfortunately, there are a few tests which don't pass for `Foo2` yet and other tests which don't pass for `Foo3`. Think of them as specification for `Foo` where incomplete implementations can already be useful. I'd like a way to mark some inherited tests as pending (or hiding them completely).

Breaking `FooTests` into traits based on what subclasses tests work for isn't a solution: new subclasses may be added in the future, including in external projects.

Using `JUnitSuite` would help, since tests would just be methods and could be overridden normally, but it's probably too late to do.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385003/avoid-inheriting-super-class-tests-in-scalatest, because I want to keep most tests.

Comment: Probably you have already thought about wrapping those `test`s into methods, why didn't you go that way?

Comment: @EndeNeu Wrapping them in methods would require repeating all tests I want to include in each subclass (assuming you mean what I think of). As said in the above comment, I want to keep most of tests in most subclasses, so that's a lot of duplication.

Comment: What I mean is `abstract class FooTest ... { def test1() = { test("test") {...}}; test1()} ` so now the test is wrapped in a method and called at the end of the class definition, which means that every time the class is defined it will be run. You could now extend this class and override the method and add some custom behaviour, not sure if you don't want this test to be run every time the class is extended or not.

Comment: Make like Volkswagen: when parent `Foo` detects that it is being tested, delegate to a mock object that passes. OK, I finally got to make that joke. But it's a good question: a test runner could handle unimplemented `???` uniformly, but not if the failure mode is just failed assertions. Maybe an annotation marks the API or SPI as unstable and the tests just report what works. You don't even care what the implementer thinks should work, only what actually works.

Comment: @EndeNeu Ah, I see. That makes more sense, I forgot to mentally include the call in the abstract class. But I like Ptak's answer better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any code that you put in the abstract class body will get executed, period. If you wish to be able to exclude some tests, you need a custom solution. One of them is to exclude tests based on their names:

```
abstract class FooTest extends FunSuite with Matchers {
  def excluded: Seq[String] = Seq.empty

  override def test(testName: String, testTags: Tag*)(testFun: => Unit) =
    if (excluded.contains(testName)) ()
      else super.test(testName, testTags: _*)(testFun)

  test("method1") { ... }
  test("method2") { ... }
```

Then in the subclass you can exclude some tests as follows:

```
class Foo1Test extends FooTest {
  override def excluded = Seq("method2")
}
```

You can of course come up with some more syntax sugar, but I don't think it's worth much more time if it's only meant to hide tests until they are implemented.

Also note that with this approach hides the tests completely, but you might as well mark them, tag them, or do whatever you want before calling `test`.

Comment: I agree about "not worth the time"; a build file notation might be more lightweight for beleaguered developers. If the impl subclasses have custom test classes, you can normally exclude `Foo1Test.method2`.